# Hide null values from response object in webservice

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services

I have a web service that returns an object (response). The object contains parameters that depend on the request type.

I want to hide the null parameters in the response so that it only returns the parameters related to the submitted request

JSon response:

```
{
    "ProcessRequestJsonResult":" 
    {
        \"RequestTypeId\":0,
        \"StatusCode\":2010,
        \"status\":null,
        \"ResponseMessage\":\"Customer is assosiated with another request\",
        \"ResponseLanguage\":null,
        \"LandLineAreaCode\":null,
        \"LandLine\":null,
        \"LandLineOwner\":null,
        \"Conts\":null,
        \"Ownership\":null,
        \"OwnershipString\":null,
        \"Co\":null,
        \"ContractDate\":\"\\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\\/\",
        \"BillingCycle\":null,
        \"BillingLog\":null,
        \"ActivationDate\":\"\\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\\/\",
        \"FirstLoginDate\":\"\\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\\/\",
        \"CustomerTechnicalDetails\":null,
        \"CustomerQuota\":null,
        \"CustStat\":null,
        \"CurrentStatus\":null,
        \"Case\":null,
        \"CustomerProducts\":null,
        \"CustomerTransaction\":null,
        \"Discount\":null,
        \"IdType\":null,
        \"IdNumber\":null,
        \"Idtables\":null
    }"
}
```

I want to hide any returned parameter that equals null. Does anyone have any idea if it's even possible

Comment: What framework is used for implementing web services? Is it ASP.NET MVC/Web API or WCF?

Comment: a piece of code to understand what you exactly mean by "null parameters in the response"

Comment: If JSON.NET serialization engine is used, this could be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471841/json-serialisation-removing-empty-keys